# Does Galera Arbitrator require a SST?

Tags: mysql, percona-xtradb-cluster, galera

Does Galera Arbitrator require a SST? It says it's stateless but it's not clear if a SST i required. 
The reason for asking is that I'm having a large database and would like to skip the SST if possible.

Comment: This is perhaps the most incomprehensible question/answer set I've seen in awhile.

Answer (score 1):

It requested a SST in the meaning of a position, but a file transfer was not needed. Galera Arbitrator is like a mysql server but without storing any data.